# How can I memorize complex hindu slokas?

Tags: vishnu, mantras, shloka, teaching

I recently got profound interest in learning Hindu slokas. But I am having very hard time memorizing them. How can I do this. The slokas I am trying are AdityaHridayam, Suryashtakam, BhagavadGita, Govinda Namalu, Hanuman Chalisa.

Comment: First know the meter used in stotra... then find method of chanting of that meter... then it becomes easy....

Comment: the human mind learns something physically through only two methods - either by physical motion or by speaking. To memorize you must repeat a sloka many times on a daily basis. How often you repeat determines how quickly you learn. Read out loud 4 lines 25 times, 2-3 times a day. You will find that in a few days you can repeat it without reading. Go on to the next 4 lines. You will soon learn your own pace for memorization. The more you repeat daily the more quickly you can memorize.

Comment: Just hear them multiple times. I memorized Hanuman Chalisa within one month

Comment: How is this question related to Hinduism.

Comment: @Anurag I think it's related because OP has a problem with verses found in Hindu scripture. He has no problem memorizing English sayings (for example).

Answer (score 7):

listening the shlokas with audio source is also very effective method to memorize shlokas (if possible). We tend to quickly grasp or  memorize what  we hear and our mind repeats it, keeps it in memory. By this method we also get familiar with the pace and exact pronunciation of words, shlokas. 
As we all are familiar with our experience related to songs, we tend to memorize and repeat the songs we listen. The same rule also applied to shlokas. Also combining  the methods stated above by all , Its more simpler to do the thing.

Comment: Good advice for remembering sloka

Answer (score 3):

If you really wanted to memorize Hindu shlokas then you must follow habit daily basis according to my opinion.

Here, I want to share my personal experience. I have memorized Adhyay 12 and 15 in shrimad Bhagavat Geeta in 2 months. What I did for achieving this?

I woke up Early in the morning.

I have just read the first 10 shlokas of Adhyay-12 with my father. He Knows correct pronunciation of every shlokas.

This process goes on continue 15 days and I couldn't believe that I have memorized 10 shlokas of Adhyay-12.

Finally, This way I have memorized whole these two Adhyay And still I don't forget both.

**One most important thing is that you should not lose the consistency of every day of your reading shlokas.**

Personal benefits for me:

I have little stammering in my childhood. After doing memorize and mesmerize of shlokas, It was completely out of my mouth.

My memory power becomes more strong.

Answer (score 2):

In addition of the all answers,

1. Should memorize you have to clear your mind/soul & physically
2. The time is very very important to memorize between (5 AM to 6 AM)
3. Don't carry a lot of Slokas/Mantras in overnight.

Split Mantras by Week days

1. Monday ... (God Sivan)
2. Tuesday ....(God Murugan) .... like etc all the days continue by this method.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to remember shlokas of Sanskrit language of Hindu holy books, then first of all you have to learn Sanskrit deeply.(It is required for all of us Hindus, because we are nearer to miss our valuable ideas that our Vedas and Upanishads provided to us.) And then, start with a small book of Sanskrit shlokas, say "Shikshapatri" by Bhagwan Swaminarayan which is a very small book containing all Hindu ideas and niyams(rules that must be followed by each Human being to have a peaceful and a happy life). One important thing to note is that clearly read a translation given below the shlokas to understand the meaning of the Sanskrit words. And then go to some big books containing many shlokas in Sanskrit, say Shrimad Bhagwad Gita, a small part of Shrimad Bhagwad Purana. You will definitely see your improvement in Sanskrit shlokas remembrance and understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to know any meaning of any words. You don't have to learn any Sanskrit. Feel the devotion and recite. The more you put in your mind with understanding, the ego grows and thoughts multiply. The aim of this path is to be free from thoughts and not accumulate more. I have learned many mantras without knowing what any of it means, but only my love and deep feeling of devotion. More than your understanding, your feelings have to be there. Recite each line multiple times until you can repeat without reading.

All the best to you!
God's Grace.

Comment: You should cite sources (for one doesn't have to know meaning, etc.)

Comment: @Pandya Isn't there a story about a famous sage? The sage was walking when he saw a man crying at the Bhagavad Gita. When the sage enquired why is he crying, people told that man is illiterate. When the sage asked the man directly, the man said his Guru told him to read Bhagavad Gita, and seeing the picture of God he was happy and crying. Then the sage said that the man is reading it correctly. If I remember correctly, the sage was Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu. I think if this story is true, then the answer is also true.

Comment: @Shashwat We insist on citing sources in oder to maintain quality. It has nothing to do whether answer is right or wrong. Visit [Why we insist on source requirement](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/786/277).

Comment: @Pandya but is the story true? I remember reading it somewhere but do no remember if it is correct or not. Do you know?